# AWS Cognito - Resend Verification Link to an User

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I'm building an application with AWS Cognito and AWS AppSync.

**My Problem:**
I want to an User, after signUp, for some reason (not important) he did not receive the Verification E-mail (which is a Link, not a Code).
The user goes back to the application and asks for another Verification E-mail.

**Tried:**

I tried the following solutions,

-> Using resendConfirmationCode function of AWS-SDK.
-> Using Auth Amplify API with the function resendSignUp[
-> Using the following npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js) Use Case #3

I Always end up on this message: "Cannot reset password for the user as there is no registered/verified email or phone_number"

I want that the function resends the verification Link to an User, so he does not have a E-mail verified yet.

**What do I expect?**

If the user does not receive an E-mail with the verification Link, he can use a function to call again for this e-mail.
As I'm working with Links, I would rather prefer a Link for this, but if is not possible, a Code will be fine, and I change it on Cognito Lambda-Triggers.

Hope you guys be able to help me :)